# How to Authenticate Microsoft dynamics CRM for liveid using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using windows application to connect with Microsoft Dynamics CRM . Here I can login using online federation and on-Premise types but when I try to login with Live Id credentials, I am getting security error like `"An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."`

So pls tell me how can I get login using with live id details.

Note: I am using SDK authenticationwithnohelp code for login

Answer (score 0):

The best way to troubleshoot this kind of thing is to look at the inner fault details that are generated when a call to the CRM web service fails. The exception type thrown is usually:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Wrap your code in a try / catch block and examine the exception Detail and Detail.InnerFault objects:

```
        try
        {
            // Connection code here
        }
        catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
        {
            string exceptionMessage = ex.Message;
            int errorCode = -1;

            // Check for fault detailed information 
            if (ex.Detail != null)
            {
                // Check for the Detail InnerFault
                if (ex.Detail.InnerFault != null)
                {
                    // Get the inner fault message and code - this is where the useful information is
                    exceptionMessage += " - " + ex.Detail.InnerFault.Message;
                    errorCode = ex.Detail.InnerFault.ErrorCode;
                }
                else
                {
                    // No InnerFault was defined, get the Detail message and code
                    if (exceptionMessage != ex.Detail.Message)
                    {
                        // The Detail.Message will usually be the same as the outer exception
                        exceptionMessage += " - " + ex.Detail.Message;
                    }

                    errorCode = ex.Detail.ErrorCode;
                }
            }

            // Output exceptionDetails and errorCode here
            Trace.WriteLine("Exception message: " + exceptionMessage);
            Trace.WriteLine("Exception code: " + errorCode);
        }
```

The exception error code property can also be helpful. The error code is returned as a format decimal, for example -2147167730

You can cross-reference this against the list of error codes returned by the CRM web service on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328182.aspx

However, first you need to convert the error code from decimal to the hex format used on MSDN.

Using the example error code -2147167730:

1. Open the Windows Calculator
2. Select Programmer mode (Alt + 3)
3. Select Dec (Decimal) and paste in the error code (-2147167730)
4. Select Hex, and the code will be converted to 'FFFFFFFF8004D20E'
5. Remove the leading FFFFFFFF characters, and then look on the MSDN error code page for '8004D20E'